# Dropdown aberto

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma propriedade para que eu possa deixar um dropdown aberto no carregamento da pagina, só fechando se o usuario clicar na aba.

Obs: estou usando bootstrap.

```
 <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i>&nbsp &nbspApólices <i class="caret"></i></a>
    <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Cadastrar Apólice</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Visualizar Apólice</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Editar Apólice</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Excluir Apólice</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Exportar como PDF</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione essa classe (.stay-open)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu stay-open">
```

Depois aplique no css !important

```
.stay-open {display:block !important;}
```